# Kivy: How to change window size?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm starting to write a program using [`kivy`](http://kivy.org/#home), but I have some problems understand how it deals with sizes.

For example:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.5.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self): return Button(text='Some text')

MyApp().run()
```

The above program works, but it creates a **huge** window. Trying to set `size=(100, 100)` does not change anything. Setting `size_hint=(None, None)` will show a button with the correct size, but it is placed randomly inside a *still* huge window.
Trying to set the size of `MyApp` does not change anything too.

How do I create a window with the same size of the button?
It should be a simple enough task, but looking at the documentation and example I can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 120):

There're currently two ways:

- Before the window is created:

  ```
  import kivy
  kivy.require('1.9.0')

  from kivy.config import Config
  Config.set('graphics', 'width', '200')
  Config.set('graphics', 'height', '200')
  ```
- Dynamically after the Window was created:

  ```
  from kivy.core.window import Window
  Window.size = (300, 100)
  ```

Comment: This works perfectly, I was having this exact same problem and could not find anything to help me, fortunately i found this... thanks so much Martin

Comment: Is  there a way to make the window fit to the whole screen? regardless of resolution?

Comment: @Yair You mean fullscreen or windowed but with the size of the screen?

Comment: Sorry, I don`t really see the difference. I guess I mean full screen.

Comment: Ok, now I can see the difference. I actually meant Windowed size. Was looking at https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html but couldn`t find the right command

Answer (score 21):

Use this:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (300, 100)
```

If you use

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '200')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '200')
Config.write()
```

this will lead to loss of default screen size!
Default screen size is really useful.

Comment: It could be a good idea to explain why it's "really useful".

Comment: Um, if you want to maintain the "default" screen size - DON'T use `Config.write()` - it's not needed for runtime changes. Be sure you set the size before the line `from kivy.app include App` of for KivyMD `from kivymd.app include MDApp`

Answer (score 10):

I would comment on martin's answer, but I don't have the reputation. When setting the config file, be sure to "write" your changes:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '200')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '200')
Config.write()
```

It's exactly like committing info to a database, if you know anything about that.

Comment: Config.write() makes the changes permanent. They will be used as default then.

Comment: To make it clear, this make it the default for all kivy applications which I don't know if it is a good idea.

Comment: *"It's exactly like committing info to a database, ..."* — **exactly** or **like**?

Comment: We'll go with "like" :3

Answer (score 1):

Using `Config.write()` will set your changes to the default settings. If you accidentally run this and want to revert the changes, you can either run `Config.write()` again with the default values (therefore reverting your changes) or you can open up `$HOME/.kivy/config.ini` with a text editor and edit it.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, please don't post comments as answers.