# Changing size of two different kivy screens

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, fullscreen

I have two screens in a Kivy program. The first one represents the login screen, so it needs to be smaller, while the other has the data, so I need to make it full screen.

I tried to use

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '350')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '250')
```

But, the problem is with this the other screen's size has also decreased, help me if you have any idea what I need to do to have different sizes for different screens, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change window size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014955/how-to-change-window-size)

Comment: No its not, here I am trying to change sizes for two different windows not for a single windows (which the mentioned question answers)

Answer (score 1):

I answered almost the identical question earlier today.  Code your python similar to this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Main(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Window.size = (900, 500)     

class Login(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Login, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Window.size = (400, 300)


class MultiScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Screen_Manager()

MultiScreenApp().run()
```

with a multiscreen.kv file similar to this:

```
<Screen_Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    Login:
    Main:

<Login>:
    name: 'login'
    Button:
        text: 'Go to Main'
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'

<Main>:
    name: 'main'
    Button:
        text: 'Go to Login'
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'login'
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a method like

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

def update_window_size(width, height):
    # Validate width and height then
    Window.size = (width, height)
```

and call it with the desired height and width anywhere you want.

___ Edit 1 - Adding sample. Change Screen size in the `Screen`'s initilization

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window

sm = ScreenManager()


class Main(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()


class Login(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Login, self).__init__()
        # Change login screen size in it's __init__
        update_window_size(250, 250)


def update_window_size(width, height):
    # Validate width and height then
    Window.size = (width, height)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I am quite new to Kivy, can you please expalin this with an example, like for example O have two classes for two screens:                                                           class LoginScreen(Screen) for  <LoginScreen>:            and     class DataDisplayScreen(class) for <DataDisplayScreen> how should I move forward?? Thanks

Comment: @Mahdi I added a sample with two screens

Comment: Thanks again fr the effort, but I getting this error:                                           child = cls(__no_builder=True)
 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__no_builder'