# Kivy module switch widget pressed anywhere

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I have a kivy file with several widgets, one of them is a switch.
The problem is that wherever I press on the screen, it flips the switch.

I have 2 other widgets - one of them is a check-box and another is radio-buttons, which also have some problems and I think they are occuring because of the switch.
The problem is that in order to press them I need to press on a different part of the screen and not on the widget itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I am using Windows only for development.

Comment: Please add  the shortest code necessary to reproduce your problem, otherwise it is hard to help you, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sounds familiar to problem I faced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46680362/1113207). Didn't you changed `Window.size` manually?

Comment: See update, I am using Windows only and not android. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a switch that is larger than you expect. From the documentation of the switch: "The entire widget is active, not just the part with graphics. As long as you swipe over the widget’s bounding box, it will work." I would try changing the background of the switch to see how big it really is.