# Disable fullscreen kivymd

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, material-design, kivymd

I have been working on some projects with kivy for a while, some of them requiring fullscreen, but now I want to learn kivymd. The problem is that my kivymd app opens in fullscreen, how can I change that from the code? Also, how can I change the default window size of the application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014955/kivy-how-to-change-window-size

Comment: @Xyanight, it works on kivy, but doesn't in kivymd!

Answer (score 1):

Set the window size BEFORE importing MD modules and BEFORE importing the `kivy.core.window.Window` module!

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '200')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '200')

[impots MD modules]
[impots kivy.core.window.Window modules]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple resizing the windows but note one thing while packing this for android apk you should remove these lines:

```
     from kivy.core.window import Window
     Window.size =[x ,y]
```

The x and y variables is upto your choice

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines at the top your code. change the values to adjust the size of your window to your desired size.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (370, 700)
```